# How to get User Email who is submitting the form and save it

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm building a form using google app maker. Now I want to implement something so That I can save the name/Email of the user who is submitting the form without entering their own email address. But I have no idea how to do that. But when they send email, it shows their gmail address.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Model events onBeforeSave `record.YourField = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know If someone still need help with this. Try to add in your client script

```
app.Datasource.YourDataSource.item.YourField = app.user.username;
```

This worked for me.